# React - typescript TypeScript error: This expression is not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Changing a file to use to use typescript. Learning typescript.

I changed the signature to be

```
export default function PostForm( post: PostInterface, username: string, posts: PostInterface[], setPosts: PostInterface[], setPostMessage:string ) {
...
const newPost = { title, content, author: username, slug, created };
setPosts([newPost, ...posts])
```

but now I get an error with `setPosts`:

```
TypeScript error: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'PostInterface[]' has no call signatures.  TS2349
```

and vScode is saying `this expression is not callable`.

Comment: `setPosts: PostInterface[]` - `setPosts` is an *array* type, according to the signature you provided; why would it be callable? What's unclear from the error?

Answer (score 0):

The type of `setPosts` is `PostInterface[]` or in other words, setPosts is supposed to be an array of `PostInterface`s. You probably want the type of `setPosts` to be some sort of function. For example:

```js
setPosts: (newPosts: PostInterface[]) => PostInterface[]
// OR, if setPosts doesn't return anything
setPosts: (newPosts: PostInterface[]) => void
```

Comment: either way I get `Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: `export default function PostForm( post: PostInterface, username: string, posts: PostInterface[], setPosts: (PostInterface[]) => void, setPostMessage:string ) {`

Comment: either way error is at the arrow of the arrow function

Comment: @MichaelDurrant please read the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type, you need to include a *name* for the parameter.